# Prestashop 1.7.8 form fields validation

Tags: validation, prestashop-1.7

How to add custom class for example "error" to requiered fields when customer forget to fill them?

For example in registration form. When customer forget to fill multiple fields and click on Submit how to highlight all that missing fields?

Answer (score 0):

Not a pretty solution, but it works

```
  $('#login-form').submit(function() {
        var $inputs = $('#login-form :input');
        let hasError = false;
        $inputs.each(function() {
            if(!$(this).val() && $(this).prop('required')){
                $(this).addClass('required-error-class'); 
                hasError = true;
            }    
        });
        if(hasError){
            return false;
        }else {
            return true;
        };
    });
```

A nicer solution is to use `e.preventDefault` and ajax